# Old SQL Query Syntax not supporting in new MYSQL Version

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin, xampp

I have an old SQL Query which is not supporting in the new MySQL version.
I don't know the version of this query. How should I make it to support? Will I have to convert this?

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_AdminLogin] (
    [LoginName] [varchar] (50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL ,
    [Password] [varchar] (50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL 
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: That query looks like SQL Server syntax and not MySQL

Comment: An old sql?OR do you want people to do the work for you converting from sql server?

Comment: @juergend yes my bad I figured it out lately. Anyways, thanks.

Comment: @Mihai, Did I mentioned anything about asking someone to do the task for me? Get a life and post helpful comments -_-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a SQL Server query. I was using it in MySQL. -_- My bad.

Answer (score -1):

This query works in MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `AdminLogin` (
    `LoginName` varchar(50) NOT NULL ,
    `Password` varchar(50)
);
```

Comment: I was working on SQL Server Query, I confused it with MySQL. I worked it out. Anyways thanks :)